# How long can i run this appliance?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

How long could I run a 115 Vac window unit on a 12v 200Ah battery (using a 700W inverter from a 400W solar panel and assuming 100% efficiency)?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework-like questions should show what has been tried and narrow the question to one conceptual difficulty.

Comment: This is not going to work.  get a 12V air con.

Comment: this cannot be answered ... you did not say how much power the window unit uses

Answer (score 2):

A 700VA inverter can only produce 6A at 120V, it will not be able to start the compressor in a window AC.  So, zero hours, unless you only run the fan.

Answer (score -1):

i will give you most basic calculation

assuming your battery in good condition and new with trusted specification.

12*200=2400W/h this can steady until 1hours rate = 2400W total output

assuming your converter connected with load is 100% back to back without loss power which is highly unlikely..
2400/700 = ~3.43Hours

the calculation with solar panel is different because you doesn't gives how much sunlight and how long it will directed to sun..

Comment: Where does this 10 hours come from?

Comment: oh yeah i forget.. its way overpowered it's discharge rate of some battery not leaded acid battery..  yes you are right only capable 3.42Hours. i will edit